# Strange Chrome behaviour in for-in cycle

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, scope, comparison

I came across a strange behavior of Chrome when running for-in cycle inside a wrapping function.

Say, we have an object:

```
obj = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4 };
```

Excution of this code:

```
var sum = 0;
for (var val in obj) {
  sum += obj[val];
}
```

is two times slower than calling this function:

```
function sumObj(obj) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var val in obj) {
    sum += obj[val];
  }
}
```

like:

```
sumObj(obj);
```

Edge and Firefox browsers handle this code equally.

Why Chrome handles function call faster than internal code directly?

You can find performance test [there](https://prozoroff.github.io/jsperf/?%7B%22initial%22%3A%22obj%20%3D%20%7B%20%27a%27%3A%201%2C%20%27b%27%3A%202%2C%20%27c%27%3A%203%2C%20%27d%27%3A%204%20%7D%3B%5Cn%5CnsumObj%20%3D%20function(obj)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20var%20sum%20%3D%200%3B%5Cn%20%20for%20(var%20val%20in%20obj)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20sum%20%2B%3D%20obj%5Bval%5D%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%2C%22iterations%22%3A1000000%2C%22tasks%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22forin%22%2C%22body%22%3A%22var%20sum%20%3D%200%3B%5Cnfor%20(var%20val%20in%20obj)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20sum%20%2B%3D%20obj%5Bval%5D%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22forin%20function%22%2C%22body%22%3A%22sumObj(obj)%3B%22%7D%5D%7D).

Comment: Interesting question. I think it must be related to the implementation of the `v8` engine. Actually from my point of view there should not be any difference regarding the performance.

Comment: Remember to include the `hasOwnProperty` check when using `for in` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in this is to filter out any inherited.

Comment: Engine specific ofc but perhaps because the function is an optimizable unit whereas the other code is just floating about in the soup of the global scope.

Comment: @AlexK. seems likely, I imagine Chrome may optimise the function because it's expected to be called more often, but just a piece of global code will likely run once. Also, you shouldn't _really_ have to do such code in the global scope. Still, it's an interesting observation.